# how to write a test class for this trigger, could anyone provide me the test class code for this trigger?

Tags: trigger, unit-test

```
trigger CTC_Update on Appraisal__c(after insert, before update) {
    List < appointment__c > AppList = New List < appointment__c > ();
    Set < Id > AppointIds = New Set < Id > ();
    For(Appraisal__c A: Trigger.New) {
        AppointIds.Add(A.ApplicantName__c);
    }
    List < appointment__c > AppointList = [Select Id, Current_CTC__c from appointment__c where id =: AppointIds];
    For(Appraisal__c Aps: Trigger.New) {
        appointment__c A = new appointment__c();
        For(appointment__c App: AppointList) {
            IF(Aps.ApplicantName__c == App.ID) {
                A.Id = App.Id;
                IF(Aps.amount_of_Increment__c != 0 && Aps.amount_of_Increment__c != NULL) {
                    A.Current_CTC__c = App.Current_CTC__c + Aps.amount_of_Increment__c;
                }
                IF(Aps.Increment_Percentage__c != 0 && Aps.Increment_Percentage__c != NULL) {
                    A.Current_CTC__c = App.Current_CTC__c + (App.Current_CTC__c * Aps.Increment_Percentage__c);
                }
            }
            AppList.Add(A);
        }
    }
    IF(AppList != NULL) {
        Update AppList;
    }
}
```

Comment: welcome to salesforce stackexchange, this is very broad question, you must try yourself before asking the community to answer you, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: You write a test class by writing a test class. I know that sounds silly, you haven't really told us why you are not sure how to write your test class or what question you'd like to ask us on doing so. Please update your question to include more details. We will not simply write the test code, you have to do that. When you get stuck and tell us where you got stuck, we'll help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am providing you the sample test code for your trigger but I would suggest you to try it yourself also first in future and then let us know if you face any issues with it. This will enable you to learn more the basics of the coding standards and functionality.

Test class is basically written to do the unit testing of your code. Your test class primary contains of test data for the objects which you are using in your original code. You must always use Assert statements to verify the functionality of your code.

Below is the sample test class for your trigger. You can add more assert statements in it to verify the functionality of your business requirement.

```
@IsTest
Public Class CTC_Update_Test
{
    Public Static TestMethod Void Test1()
    {
        Test.StartTest();

        Appointment__c Appoint = New Appointment__c(Name = 'Test App' , Current_CTC__c = 12.00);
        Insert Appoint;
        System.AssertNotEquals(Null, Appoint.Id);

        Appraisal__c Apprase = New Appraisal__c(Name = 'Test Appraise' , Amount_Of_Increment__c = 10 , Increment_Percentage__c =10 , Appointment__c = Appoint.Id);
        Insert Apprase;
        System.AssertNotEquals(Null, Apprase.Id);

        Test.StopTest();
    }
}
```